# How to reload browser tab in a Flutter Web Application

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have a Flutter Application running on web and I need to reload the browser tab programmatically, and I wonder if there is something similarly with html.window.close() but for reload. Is there any way to do this in Flutter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).[reload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) method

```dart
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;

FlatButton(
  child: Text('Refresh'),
  onPressed: () {
    html.window.location.reload();
  },
),
```